# Skype video not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: video, skype, webcam

I'm running Skype on Ubuntu (i3 as windows manager).

Skype seems to work fine for audio and it detects my camera but the video is black. When I open Google Hangouts I can see my video output perfectly.

Any tips on debugging this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Install the libv4l 32bit version (even if you are using 64bit)

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0:i386
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't work for me; still see black screen